# In Maven, how to run a plugin based on a specific profile

Tags: maven, profile

I have a Maven project that has 3 modules. These are built by the parent `pom.xml`

I now have a requirement that I need to run one plugin from inside one of the sub modules' `pom.xml` files based on the profile selected.

How can I specify that this plugin should only run when a certain profile is used in build?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hot to disable buildnumber-maven-plugin through cmd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851475/hot-to-disable-buildnumber-maven-plugin-through-cmd)

Answer (score 38):

Please read the documentation on build profiles here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

You basically need to define a profile in your sub-module's POM and include that plugin in the profile's `plugin` section. Using the plugin's `execution` tag, you can define which build *phase* the plugin should run in.

See here for an example: [Using maven profiles to control build execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684837/using-maven-profiles-to-control-build-execution)

Answer (score 2):

What worked in this case for me was to use the same profile as in the main pom.xml inside the sub modules pom.xml.

basically what I wanted was to be able to run a plugin from inside the sub modules pom.xml, only when a certain profile 'say X' was run in the main pom.xml

What I did was create a profile 'X' inside the sub modules pom.xml and placed that plugin inside this profile.

Now when profile X is run from main pom.xml, this plugin from the sub module's pom file is also run.

was other profiles , this plugin is not triggered.

Hope it helps someone:)

Comment: You could post some relevant part of the pom.xml, that'd make your post even more valuable! :)

Comment: truely so when x then y or z?